# Create wrapper function around ajax calls

Tags: ajax, angularjs, promise

I want to create a wrapper around my API calls in AngularJS like

```
function MakeCall (url){
$http.get(url, config).success(successfunction);

return response;
}
```

Can you help me how to wait for the call to complete and get the final response from the call. In above code the "return response" is what I want to get after the completion of call. This function will be used like

```
response = MakeCall("to some url");
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> response = MakeCall("to some url");
> ```

That's not how promises work. You [cannot synchronously `return` the result of an ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call).

You just seem to want to return the promise that `$http.get()` already yields from your function:

```
function MakeCall (url){
    return $http.get(url, config).success(successfunction);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
MakeCall("to some url").then(function(response) {
    …
});
```